# How to get enum value names from int column in SQL Server database for a .NET class

Tags: sql-server, enums

I am trying to query an int column which represents an enum in a .NET class. I want the result of the query to be the name of the int value. Please keep in mind that I am not trying to do this through .NET code, just working with plain SQL queries here.

I could create another table with these values and their corresponding names and then join with it to get the desired result but that would mean having to maintain the values.

Is there any other on-the-fly solution I can use?

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to call `myEnum.ToString()`

i guess to start from the beginning:

```
int dbValue = 1;
var myEnum = (myEnumType)dbValue;
string enumName = myEnum.ToString();
```